# How to display a json array in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

Hi I am new to javascript/JS or jquery . All i know is to code in php but i want to learn JS too.
My code didnt diplay the get data from json_encode to HTML TABLE.
please help me to do this. I search all way how to that. but they always use like *var* but when i try to do the same i didnt display anything so i start again from basics.

what i want is to display the data get from process.php json_encode into my html table ***TBODY part only*** not the whole table.

please correct me if there are something missing.(i.e jquery plugin? where to download please)

below are my code.

For Index.html

```html
   
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>LEARN AJAX</title>
     <style type="text/css">
      #mytable,td{
          border:0px solid blue;
      }
     </style>
     
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <table>
       <thead>
        <th>ID No.</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <!--*/data should go Here-- >
         <!--Data from process.php-->
    
       </tbody>
    
      </table>
    
    </body>
    </html
```

For Process.php

```
<?php

include ('connection.php');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$return_arr = array();

$sql="SELECT * FROM members";

if ($result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql )){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['name'] = $row['fname'];
        $row_array['address'] = $row['ad'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
 }


 //echo json_encode($return_arr);
$result = json_encode($return_arr);


?>
```

For my DB connection:

```
<?php
    //for MySQLi OOP
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydatabase');
    if($conn->connect_error){
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Hi, i added the code. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your tbody just loop through the result you get from php:

```
<tbody>
  <?php
     foreach ($result as $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>"+$value['id']+"</td><td>"+$value['fname']+"</td><td>"+$value['ad']+"</td></tr>";
     }
   ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: shouldn't the <th> elements be <td> elements instead - they are in the tbody? and what about the <tr> elements if there is more than one row of content?

Comment: Hi thank you for the prompt response, but it seems it still have error. 
like where should i place the process.php? or how to call it?

Comment: @D.V.D. I find a way to insert the code. but error still. it says like this 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach() '

Comment: @Jexten you need to add `echo $result` in you php as it may not be finding it

Comment: @D.V.D. I added the `echo $result` outside the foreach loop. it displays the data but not in the table coz' error still display _Invalid argument supplied for foreach() _

Comment: @Jexten I mean in your Process.php at the bottom below `$result = json_encode($return_arr);` As you are assigning it to the result but not echoing it meaning you are not sending it back. Also is your php and html in one file or you are calling it by JS, JQ or ajax?

Comment: @D.V.D Yes, but still get error like i said. invalid argument supplied for foreach. I think something is missing or wrong in foreach ?